# How to compute a set of nodes neighbor's degree in spark graphx

Tags: scala, apache-spark, graph, spark-graphx

i am working on a graph that has some nodes. i have selected nodes with degree one and i want to compute the degree of neighbor that is connected to it.

i have loaded the edge list with `GraphLoader` to RDDs  and grouped nodes based on their degrees. 
then we filter nodes with degree = 1 and put them in the variable `degree_ones_temp_value`
imagine we have two nodes with degree one with IDs: 12 and 35.
node with Id=12 is connected to node 1 with degree 10 and node with Id=35 is connected to node 34 with degree 18.

variable `degree_ones_temp_value` is a RDD that stores nodes with degree =1 and as mentioned nodes 12 and 35 degree is equal to 1.

```
degree_ones_temp_value:

  12
  35
```

i want to call `something` function by calling `map` on each node in the `degree_ones_temp_value` ,that the function gets node ID and computes the neighbors of a node and gives the length of that array, so this would be the degree of that node.

```
    def something(vertex: VertexId) = {
    val i = graph.collectNeighborIds(EdgeDirection.Either).lookup(vertex)
    (vertex,i.length)

  }

   val result = degree_ones_temp_value.map(something)
   result.foreach(println)
```

i expected to get this result:

```
(12,10)
(35,18)
```

the first number is the ID of node with degree =1 that we passed it to function and the second number is degree of the neighbor of node with degree one.

when i execute this code i get errors:

```
Exception in task 0.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 10)
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

please help me with this problem??
why i get errors when i call a function inside the map??